# executing a function in background? Do I need threading for this? c++

Tags: c++, linux, queue, tcpserver

I am trying to automate some data entry so I implemented a tcp client and server, the client will send file names then the server will go into a shared folder and imports that file the database.

my problem is that file names could be sent at a faster rate than "importing to database". so I made a queue (which I am not sure how to set the size on it) and I push file names on the queue then execute

```
PushToDatabase(filename);
```

what I am trying to do is:

```
queue<string> q;
char *data = new char[1024];
ReadFromClient(data);
//now 'data' has a filename
q.push(data);
PushToDatabase(q.front());  // I want to execute this in the background
q.pop();
```

I am not sure if I need to implement threading to make this work or not I also have no clue how this could be done in c++

Any other ideas??

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the number of files that you are looking at processing, you should take a look at [ring buffers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). You could allocate a fixed size and should be able to continuously read and write to it without buffer over/under run concerns if implemented properly. I think boost has a circular buffer container that you could use, but you'll need to have mutexes to make sure it is synchronized and thread safe. This will ensure you don't read and write to the same memory locations at the same time or change variables in other threads (since the threads use a shared memory space). You could poll the ring buffer to see if there is any new data to process using semaphores, which will also eliminate the buffer over/under run concern outlined above. You should also take a look at std::atomic containers for writing variables that will be shared between threads, that way you eliminate any race conditions if two threads try to write to the same variable.

Answer (score 1):

You could use several threads.  Be very careful about synchronization issues.

Alternatively you could have a (single-threaded) [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop). You could (painfully) write it yourself above some multiplexing syscall like [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html).

Read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).

You could also use some event loop library like [libevent](http://libevent.org/) or [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html) or Glib (from GTK) or QtCore (from Qt) or [libsigc++](http://libsigc.sourceforge.net/)

Reading about [C10K](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k) and [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) and [callbacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) and [continuation-passing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) might somehow be relevant and could open your mind about potential issues and terminology. Notice that [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) has [anonymous functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#C.2B.2B) (i.e. closures).

Comment: Thanks for the links ill start exploring those, I know fork() would fork the existing process(the entire program), but could it be utilized to fork a function into a separate process ?

Comment: This is another question, but yes `fork` is forking a process and no, it cannot be used to just fork a function... since it forks a process..